# A trivial algebra problem....(number field)

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

For **F** =$$\left \{ \frac{a_{0}+a_{1}e^{1}+...+a_{n}e^{n}}{b_{0}+b_{1}e^{1}+...+b_{m}e^{m}} \right \}$$
where $$m,n\in Z^{*}\\a_{i},b_{i}\in Z\\0\leq i\leq n, 0\leq j\leq m$$
Prove that F is a number field, where e is the base of natural logarithm.
（Need a elegant proof).$$\\$$（Background assumption）：$$$$*K* is a number field when:$$$$

1. K is a subset of C.
2. $$0,1\in K$$
3. $$a,b \in K \Rightarrow a\pm b,ab \in K$$
4. $$a,b \in K,b\neq 0\Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}\in K$$

Comment: Are you saying $e$ is Euler's number? In that case, the field in question is not a finite extension of the rationals.

Comment: and a number field is an extension of $\mathbb Q$ of finite degree

Comment: The definition of a Number Field in the question comes from a Chinese linear-algebra textbook written by  Weisheng Qiu, a professor of Peking University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. A number field is a finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$. Assuming $m,b$ are not fixed your set would not be a finite extension, but also every element of a number field must be algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. But your $F$ contains $e$ (Choose $a_1 = 1$, $b_0=1$, everything else $0$).

We do know that $e$ is *not* algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I've added some useful information, would you mind checking it again?

Comment: @JinanSpring Under the assumptions you’ve given you appear to use "Number Field" as "subfield of $\mathbb C$". This is not the common concept of a number field! In your case proving this is quite simple: We do know the rational functions over $\mathbb Z$ form a field. $F$ is then the image of this field under the evaluation homomorphism at $e$. Thus $F$ is a field. (In fact due to $e$ not being algebraic the morphism is in fact an isomorphism!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a pity that I haven't dug into group theory so far. And the definition of a Number Field in the question comes from a Chinese linear-algebra textbook written by Weisheng Qiu, a professor of Peking University.